# Why is my PowerShell host running as 32-bit on a 64-bit machine?

Tags: powershell-hosting

I'm building a PowerShell host in VS 2012, currently in a C# (.NET 4.5) Console Project.  The project is configured for Any CPU and 'Prefer 32-bit' is not checked.  I've added a reference to System.Management.Automation manually by adding

```
    <Reference Include="System.Management.Automation" />
```

to the ItemGroup with the other References in the .csproj file.  I was getting odd behaviour reading from the registry (missing keys, etc.) and I realised it was looking at the x86 part.  So I ran this script in the host:

```
if ([System.IntPtr]::Size -eq 4) 
{ 
    "32-bit"
}
else
{
    "64-bit"
}
```

and got back

```
"32-bit"
```

which wasn't a surprise given the behaviour, but was a surprise given the configuration.  Anyone got any ideas?  Is there something about hosted PowerShell that has to be x86?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the off-chance, I tried checking the 'Prefer 32-bit' box, saving the project, then un-checking it and saving the project again.  After this, it built as 64-bit.  For info, this is 
Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 (11.0.60315.01).